# Fullscreen gallery plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, gallery

I have been looking for wordpress fullscreen gallery that would support WP core gallery feature and is not based on flash. It should look similar to mashable.com (i.e. http://mashable.com/2012/03/03/instagram-products-decor/) or

Answer (score 1):

I m pretty sure Mashable is using custom plugin for that. But you try this powerful plugin to do the job: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: I use Nextgen on a few projects and provides some great features. There is also a lot of add on plugins for Nextgen that extends functionability.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about such a plugin but i have used jQuery superbgimage with custom post types to create full background slideshows. 
http://dev.andreaseberhard.de/jquery/superbgimage/
hope this is helpful.